# How to customize the car color?

Tags: pc, need-for-speed-shift

My 4 year son loves this game and he wants to play every game with a different car (different color :))

I see the option to change the car color from Garage/Visuals/Paint

There I see a ring with different color gradients and inside it a box gradient colors

I could adjust the color settings only inside the box, which are limited color combination of what is selected in the ring outside.

I am pretty sure I get more color options if i can move the pointer in that ring but don't know how. I keep trying it every weekend to see the settings but I never found. I some times get doubt this can't be done in the pc because I strongly believe that it can be changed something by moving the direction pad or right pad in the xbox controller. But I am not sure how it is done using keyboard in PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found it myself yesterday. It can be done using 8 and 9 numbers (not with num pad). It spins the color wheel

Answer (score 0):

in NFS, the number keys along the top of the keyboard are used to cycle through menu controls.

I dont remember if SHIFT tells you precisely what each one does, but 7,8,9 and 0, to the left of your backspace key, should be the keys you are looking for on the standard setup